# rails how to show catery name if user select sub_category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

in my app users has_many categories categories have sub_categories in db i create parent_id with main category id

and now i dont know how show main category if user select only sub_category
User.rb

```
has_many :users_ecategories
  has_many :ecategories, through: :users_ecategories
```

Category.rb

```
class Ecategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users_ecategories
    has_many :users, through: :users_ecategories
    has_many :ecategories, class_name: 'Ecategory', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

Users_categories.rb
class UsersCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ecategory
end

views/user/show.html.erb

```
<% @user.ecategories.each do |ecategory| %>
                    <%= ecategory.name %>
                    <%= ecategory.id %>
                <% end %>
```

how to show main category name? <%= ecategory.parent_id.name %> doesn't work
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define the parent relation

```
class Ecategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users_ecategories
    has_many :users, through: :users_ecategories
    has_many :ecategories, class_name: 'Ecategory', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

    belongs_to :parent_ecategory, class_name: 'Ecategory', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

end
```

Then the call would be

```
<%= ecategory.parent_ecategory.name %>
```

Comment: thanks, i have only 1 question, if i use this <ul>
            <% @user.ecategories.each do |ecategory| %>
            <%= ecategory.parent.name %>
            <li>
              <ul>
                <% @user.ecategories.where(parent_id: ecategory.parent.id).each do |sub_ecategory| %>
                <li>
                  <%= sub_ecategory.name %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
ecategory.parent_ecategory.name duplicated but i need one category and all selected sub_categories

Comment: Parent categoties are ones that don't have parents, so `Ecategory.where(parent_id: nil)` and `@user.ecategories.where(parent_id: nil)` are parent categories